# How to tell which buildpack has staged my application in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

In Cloud Foundry, is there a way to tell which buildpack (and which version of that buildpack) has staged a given application?

I am thinking there must be a way because I can see it on the Bluemix web console, but I can't find the same information from the cf cli (tried both `cf apps` and `cf app APPNAME`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cf curl /v2/apps
```

Find your app and look at the block of data within. If you wanted to get fancy you could filter on your app name like so `cf curl /v2/apps?q=name:<appname>`

Comment: Another way of doing what @jpapejr suggested is to set the `CF_TRACE` environment variable to `true`, then run `cf app <appname>` (e.g. on Linux or OSX do `CF_TRACE=true cf app <appname>`). That's a little easier to remember than the `cf curl` query. With either of these approaches, look for  a field named `detected_buildpack` in the JSON. This value is the string returned from the buildpack's `detect` script, and is completely dependent on the buildpack. The value might include the buildpack name, version, and other info, or it might just say "Ruby".

Answer (score 4):

In the Bluemix web console, under "Files and Logs", you should have a file called **staging_info.yml**.  The contents of that file will tell you the buildpack that was detected.  Here's an example:

---

buildpack_path: /var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/5186873d-27b5-4033-ba97-a2db19d387a2_2dcb9b37027cd39d9742223e2690f16f079a0792
detected_buildpack: **Liberty for Java**(TM) (WAR, liberty-2015.4.0_0, ibmjdk-1.7.1_sr2fp11ifx-20150312,
  env)
start_command: .liberty/initial_startup.rb